# Mono.dll caused an Access Violation usando Npgsql

Tags: c#, postgresql, unity

Usando Npgsql y Unity 5.6.2f1 para conectar con PostgreSQL y el siguiente código:

```
public bool OpenDB()
    {
        string connectionString = "Host=**;Port=**;Database=**;Username=**;Password=**";


        // IDbConnection dbcon; ## CHANGE THIS TO
        try
        {
            //NpgsqlConnection dbcon;
            dbcon = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString);
            dbcon.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log("catch " + e);
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }
```

Unity se cierra y parece que da error la manera a la que intento acceder a la base de datos en cuestión.

Los plugins están instalados y he hecho todos los pasos necesarios que explican desde Npgsql. 
Adjunto error.log para añadiros más información por si alguien puede ayudarme.

Gracias de antemano[image: ![Captura error.log]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtRB1.png)

Comment: la verdad es que ese mensaje de error no dice mucho, si pones un breakpoint en el codigo donde notas que se produce el fallo?

Comment: que pasa si pones en breakpoint donde esta el catch para poder evaluar el e.Message y ver que dice realmente el mensaje de error

Comment: no estas haciendo un insert en otra parte del codigo y te da el error, por clave foranea?

Comment: Gracias! He añadido breakpoints, pero Unity se sigue cerrando... El único problema debe ser el método Open() ya que es al que hago referencia.

Comment: Normalmente este error se debe a que el tamaño del archivo que intentas leer sobrepasa el espacio libre en ram... otra posible causa son las propiedades del archivo que intentas escribir, asegúrate que los permisos de escritura del archivo al que te estás conectando en la base de datos puede ser "writable".